# Problem with compiling a mingw32 executable on linux system with boost.asio

Tags: c++, linux, boost, boost-asio

When I am compiling a Boost.asio program with the code:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_thread -pthread
```

It just works fine, but if I compile it for windows on linux system as an executable with the code:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -I /usr/include/boost -o main.exe main.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_thread -pthread
```

or

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -o main.exe main.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_thread -pthread
```

There is a compile Error

```
fatal error: boost/asio/io_service.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
```

I mean I tried so many things to solve it and it makes me so angry do you know why?

Comment: Does the mingw distribution also contain Boost? Whether g++ can find the header or not it will need an appropriately configured and compiled Boost.

Comment: Is boost installed in `/usr/include/boost` with a boost subdirectory? Normally you would add just `/usr/include` to the command line (though this would normally be added automatically by GCC)

Comment: But im using mingw to compile for windows, on g++ / gcc it just works fine

Comment: To link the mingw-compiled objects to the Boost library, mingw will need a Boost that has been configured for and compiled with mingw. The Linux libraries (and possibly even the headers) will not work. They will have been configured for a Linux, not a Windows, system and compiled by the system's regular g++ compiler. If you have a Boost library configured for mingw and compiled with mingw, groovy, but it doesn't seem to be anywhere the mingw compiler can find it. If you point at the linux version correctly, Mingw should still be able to find the header, even if it can't use it.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to Windows, you should add the [winsockets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-2-architecture-2) libraries as a compilation parameter.

```
g++ -o main.exe main.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_thread -pthread -lws2_32 -lwsock32
```

Normally only "ws2_32" is enough.

**Note:** Winsock2 (ws2_32) is an extension to Winsock1 (wsock32). A program that currently works against wsock32 should still work fine when relinked against ws2_32.